Tiny and easy DHCP for standalone hosts
I am looking for a linux dhcp-server that is easy to configure and is just running when I start it on commandline - or even better keepts in foreground and quits if I Ctrl+C it.
What I am not try to do is to setup a linux-host as as full DHCP-server for a network. Just for serving 1 oder 2 hosts that are not on the network by default a quick ip when they are set to DHCP and directly connected by cable to the host.
I am running Debian 12.

Maybe apt-get install udhcpd (adds about 60k on my system) or apt-get install dnsmasq (adds about 160k but includes a dns resolver)?

Please answer for udhcpd and I will accept. thanks

Two small DHCP servers that are available from the standard Debian repos are udhcpd, which adds about 60k to my system and dnsmasq which adds about 160k, but includes a DNS resolver. Both allow you to run them in foreground mode so you can stop  them with ctrl-c as requested.

dnsmasq is one of the normal "go to" lightweight DHCP servers.  It was designed for embedded systems, and is common on routers.
It can do both standard "dynamic DHCP" or put static entries in if you want machines to always get the same address
e.g.  (from the example file)
dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,12h

or
dhcp-range=192.168.0.0,static
dhcp-host=11:22:33:44:55:66,fred,192.168.0.60,45m

It can be made to run from the CLI without it becoming a daemon; dnsmasq -k  (or --keep-in-foreground).
